# How can I make Mavericks only route selected traffic through the connected VPN?

Tags: macos, vpn, routing, osx-mavericks

I basically only want web traffic be to routed through the connected VPN that originates from Chrome and Safari and the rest of my computer to access the internet as if the VPN were not connected.  I am using a VPN set up in the network settings of OSX.

Answer (score 0):

you can force ALL http (or any other) traffic to go through other than default interface, but you will need to configure pf (packet filter) to do "policy based" routing. ie:

printf "pass in route-to (vpn_interface vpn_gateway_addr)  proto tcp from any to any port 80\n" | pfctl -gf-

this command will force to route all http (port 80) traffic to go through